# How to prevent npm run build from deleting directories in build

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I have a SPA react app to host my personal projects. The layout is created with react, but each personal project is a directory with normal `index.html`, `.js`, and `.css` files.

I couldn't figure out how to successfully use `<Link>` to render the regular `.html` pages on click, so I'm taking the easy route for now: manually moving each directory into `build`, then linking to it with `<a href=""></a>`.

This works, but every time I rerun `npm run build` it erases all of my project directories. How can I prevent this behavior? (I'm using `create-react-app` with defaults).

tl;dr: **How to tell `npm run build` not to delete certain directories inside `build`.**

Comment: What's the definition of `build` in your `package.json`?

Comment: "build": "react-scripts build", (and I've kept `react-scripts` as default from `create-react-app`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Build folder should be cleaned up on each build. This is best practice so your project can be build by different developers, having only source code.

To achive your task you should use additional npm script which will be automatically run after build. (You may see all possible stages when scripts can be run [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts))

postbuild script should copy additional files from some path under `src` folder to `build` folder. So on each build you'll have all required files in place

Example

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postbuild": "copy .\\src\\app.js .\\build\\app.js"
},
```

Last line will copy `app.js` from `src` folder to `build` folder. The same way you can create script to recreate all required directories after each build.

Comment: Thanks Fyodor, this is exactly what I was looking for.